# Unable to understand why N1QL Queries in couchbase hangs?

Tags: azure, couchbase, sql++

I have a couchbase cluster setup (couchbase version 4.1) where there are N data nodes, 1 Query Node and 1 Index Node. Data nodes have roughly 1 million key value pairs in a single bucket. This whole setup is hosted in Microsoft Azure within a virtual network. And can assure you that each node has enough resources that RAM, CPU or Disk is not an issue.

Now i can GET/SET JSON documents in my couchbase server without any issue. I am just testing, so ports are not issue as i have opened all ports between machines for now.

But when i try to run N1QL queries (from couchbase shell or using python SDK) it does not work. The query just hangs and i don't get any reply from server. On the other hand, once in a while the query just works without any issue and then after a minute it again stops working.

I have created PRIMARY index on my bucket and any other required Global Secondary Index if needed.

I also installed sample buckets provided by couchbase. Same problems exist.

Does anyone have a clue what the issue could be?

Comment: Can you describe what EXACTLY are you trying to do,
Like, share your code, share your indexes (not primary)

Comment: So i have bucket named as `clients`. Each JSON document in `clients` has a boolean property called `transaction_successful`. So this is what i did:

`CREATE PRIMARY INDEX on clients USING GSI`

Then i just try to run:

`SELECT id, email FROM clients where transaction_successful = false LIMIT 100 OFFSET 200`

Then i keep increasing `offset` by `limit` in a loop to get records.

Comment: Can you query the Couchbase sample buckets without any issues?

Comment: No. Same problem with sample buckets.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. Couchbase cluster on Azure. N1QL endpoint is extremely flaky. One minute, it returns a query result in a second or two. The next, it just sits there and never returns. Did you find any resolution here?

Answer (score 0):

Your query hangs probably because you are straining the server too much, I don't know how many N1QL ops you are push each second, but for that type of query you will benefit the most with several tweaks, which lower cpu usage and increase efficiency.

1. Create a specific covering index such as:

   create index inx_id_email on clients(id,email) where transaction_successful=false
2. use explain keyword to check if your query is using the index.
   (`explain SELECT id, email FROM clients where transaction_successful = false LIMIT 100 OFFSET 200`)

I believe that your query/index nodes are utilized too much because you actually doing the equivalent to primary scan in relational databases.

Comment: CPU and RAM usage on the Query and Index Node is very low. (In fact nothing as i am just testing). I have created GSI or any required index. Explain shows that the query is using the Index. Weird thing is that query works occassionaly, but most of the time it just hangs.

Comment: except of CPU and RAM usage. what do you see in the server statistics under the index? (in the WebUI)